# electron builder puppeteer missing local chromium

Tags: puppeteer, electron-builder

Is used the two packag.json structure to load dependencies in electron builder config.

```
"build": {
"asar": true,
"asarUnpack": "node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/**/*",
"appId": "client.zpa",
"directories": {
  "output": "./dist-exec",
  "app": "."
},
"win": {
  "target": [
    {
      "target": "nsis",
      "arch": [ "ia32" ]
    }
  ]
},
"nsis": {
  "artifactName": "${productName}_${version}1231.${ext}"
}

...

"dependencies": {
  "serial-number": "1.3.0",
  "puppeteer": "~1.15.0",
  "hummus": "~1.0.104"
}
```

in dist/node_modules/puppeteer the folder .local-chromium is missing. Any ideas how I can force installing local chromium?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Solved via downloading chromium according to current OS (Windows/Linux/Mac OS) on first start.
And, if there is Google Chrome browser available on running machine, you can pass path to chromium in puppeteer config.
Something like this on Windows `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe` or run this
`/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister -dump | grep -i "google chrome"`
 on Mac OS to find path to Google Chrome.

I've heard that it is possible to use Electron IPC and that calls into the JavaScript boot file and then run puppeteer from there.
But haven't tried.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I wonder because it works some days ago, and I did not change anything (builder and puppeteer version). The problem using the local chromium ist that there could be a version mismatch which leads to a missfunction. So for me it was the better approach to ship local chromium with the executable matching the puppeteer version.

Comment: That's why you can download chromium at first start of the application.

Comment: where you download it? And how do you determine matching version?

Comment: Download from here - https://chromium.woolyss.com/download/en/ . Determine matching version - verify everything in my local environment with predefined chromium version and then, on user's computer, after start, check current OS and download corresponding chromium

Comment: Thx! I switch back to electron version 2.0.8 where downloading local chromium works like a charme :-(

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of searching on StackOverflow and GitHub issues, I found that no actual solutions to build the local chrome with the electron app the best solution was to set the executable path and use chrome installed on the pc but many answers said that You will do it manually but I found this better to do it using "chrome-path" npm package to set path of chrome auto in mac or Linux or Windows here it's my code  **background.js**

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer")
const chromePaths = require('chrome-paths');

//your electron init window

  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    executablePath:chromePaths.chrome,
    headless: false,
    defaultViewport: null,
    args: ['--no-sandbox', '--start-maximized' ],
    slowMo:25,
})
const page = await browser.newPage();
await page.goto("https://google.com")
await app(page)


`
```