# Chromium version on Puppeteer build

Tags: electron, puppeteer, chromium, electron-builder

I have an application using puppeteer with electron. To build it, i used electron-builder. The problem is when i try to run the code in somebody else's PC. I always have to manually install node.js and the puppeteer (22.3.0), but i want the person have to just open the .exe.

I already tried to setup it with Inno Setup, or even run a bat that install node and puppeteer, but none of it worked. The only way i found was to manually install. I don't understand why it doesn't go with the building process.

Comment: I don't understand what having to install node.js and puppeteer has to do with "Chromium version" as per your title.  It also doesn't make sense why running a batch file that installs node would not work when manually installing it does work.

Comment: Related: [Packaging Electron + Puppeteer to a .exe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64794689/), [Is there any way I can execute my node js and puppeteer program with an exe file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810069/), [How to package a electron application which is using puppeteer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77601197/), [Puppeteer fails in React app after running electron-builder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62602604/), [electron builder puppeteer missing local chromium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58856883/)

Comment: I suggest sharing more details about what you tried so far (the inno and bat script), and explain what specifically [didn't work](https://web.archive.org/web/20180124130721/http://importblogkit.com/2015/07/does-not-work/). It could be a small adjustment to fix the problem, and your attempts can shed light and help save time for future users and prospective answerers. Thanks.

Comment: And yes, picking a clearer title would be good too!